# Best method of defining a public class variable in PHP

Tags: php, class, variables

Is there any difference between these methods of declaring and setting a public class variable? Is there any reason why you would choose one over the other?

**Method 1**

```
class example {

  public $myArray;

  function __construct() {
    $this->myArray = array(1, 2, 3);
  }

  function showVar() {
    print_r( $this->myArray );
  }

}
```

**Method 2**

```
class example {

  public $myArray = array(1, 2, 3);

  function showVar() {
    print_r( $this->myArray );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case the code will be evaluated each time you create new class instance.

In second case - it will be evaluated just once when class was parsed.

That's all.

Comment: So I suppose you would only ever want to set a public class variable using the constructor if the variable had to be calculated first? And so in the case of my example where the array will never change Method 2 would be the correct one?

Comment: @Chris: sometimes it is impossible to get member calculated statically. For example if you need to put there current time. In this case you have to initialize data in the constructor.